# Using cancan to prevent access to controller

Tags: authorization, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I have an admin controller and I want that only users that are defined as admin would have access to that controller.

my ability class:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    if user.admin?
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :read, :all
    end
  end
end
```

my admin controller:

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def index
  end

  def users_list
  end
end
```

when i try to access `/admin/users_list` (either with an admin user or without) i get the following error: `uninitialized constant Admin`

What am I doing wrong? Is that the right way to restrict access to a controller?

Answer (score 31):

This is because when you are using **load_and_authorize_resource** your controller must be backed by a model named **Admin** (since your controller is called AdminController). Thus you need to either create this model or replace **load_and_authorize_resource** with:

> authorize_resource :class => false

which causes the access checks to be made against your actions rather than the model. Note this unfortunately causes the generic access symbols such as **:manage** and **:read** to stop working requiring you to refernce the controller actions directly in **ability.rb**:

> can [ :index, :users_list ], :admin

where the first argument is a array of controller actions the user can access and the second argument is the short name of the controller

Comment: Hi, what if I want to split faked resource by types. For example, I have many reports in my projects, but no models for them. Different views goes to the same action `build` in `reports_controller.rb` with specific report name.

I'm trying to define abilities like this: `can :read, :reports, name: ['Orders', 'Payments']` and then check permissions:
`if can? :read, :reports, name: 'Orders'` but error `undefined method 'name' for :reports:Symbol` is happened. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

You can put authorization in your controller

```
authorize_resource :class => false
```

or

```
authorize_resource :class => :controller
```

Then change your app/models/Ability.rb file

```
can :manage, :controller_name
```

See [this](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/22#issuecomment-481614)

Answer (score 3):

Check this to add authorization rules for non-restful-controllers:

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Non-RESTful-Controllers

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you make a generic controller, put load_and_authorize_resource then the application controller or admin controller could not find the actual class which it come from like this example. This will work.

```
class Admin::HomeController < Admin::ApplicationController
    def home    
    end
  end

  class Admin::ApplicationController < ApplicationController
    load_and_authorize_resource :class => self.class
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. My solution was define a cannot ability. Insted of define what only the Admin can do, I'm defining what the no admin user can not do. In your code would be something like this:

Admin controller:

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
 authorize_resource :class => AdminController

 def index
 end

 def users_list
 end
end
```

ability.rb:

```
class Ability
 include CanCan::Ability

 def initialize(user)
  if user.admin?
   can :manage, :all
  else
   can :read, :all
   cannot [:index, :users_list], AdminController
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: I just learned about the possibility to define methods like: `can [:show], SettingsController if user.admin?` so nifty, thanks!